# Is there a Monad which collects results and `mappend`s them?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad, monoids

I have the following pattern of a Reader with a Semigroup Element:

```
runFunction :: Reader Env Element
runFunction = do
  a <- getA
  b <- getB
  c <- getC
  return $ a <> b <> c
```

Where `getA :: Reader Env Element`.

Is there a way to:

```
runFunction = do
  getA
  getB
  getC
```

I feel like I see this pattern alot, where I *imperatively* chain monadic calls, and they get turned into a single element at the end.

Note: I don't want to do `getA >>= getB >>= getC` since `getB` isn't `:: Element -> Reader Env Element`

It feels like a State Monad, that automatically modifies state with `<>`, but I don't know.

Working with monadic code is still quite fresh to me.

Comment: The `do` block is equivalent to `getA >> getB >> getC`. You could make use of `foldr1 (<>) <$> sequenceA [getA, getB, getC]`.

Comment: Perhaps you need some variant of the `Writer` monad, which does use `<>` on the implicitly written values. A main question is: when do you want to access the result of the concatenated `Element`s? At the very end of the monadic computation? Use `Writer`. In the middle? You probably need some variant of `State`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`WriterT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#t:WriterT) monad transformer can be used to build up a monoidal value with each action.

You can use [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) to wrap your `Reader` actions into the `WriterT` monad transformer, then move the result of each action into the monad's environment by using [`tell`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#v:tell), sequence the actions, and then unwrap the result back to a single `Reader` action using [`execWriterT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#v:execWriterT).

Here is what I mean:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

wrap :: (Monad m, Monoid w) => m w -> WriterT w m ()
wrap m = lift m >>= tell

unwrap :: (Monad m) => WriterT w m a -> m w
unwrap = execWriterT

runFunction :: Reader Env Element
runFunction = unwrap $ do
    wrap getA
    wrap getB
    wrap getC
```

As you can see, this generalizes to any monad, not just `Reader`.

Comment: Oh this is really neat. If I want to access the Env, I would simply do so before I call unwrap? `runFunction = do { e <- ask; unwrap $ wrap getA }`?

Comment: @ChrisWohlert Correct, and if you're using the version of `ask` from the `mtl` package, `Control.Monad.Reader`, then you could call `ask` directly from inside the `unwrap` region. Or else you could use `lift ask`.

Answer (score 1):

```
runFunction = fmap mconcat . sequence $ [getA, getB, getC]
```

whatever the monad is.

```
fmap mconcat . sequence
  :: (Monoid b, Monad f, Traversable t) => t (f b) -> f b
```

List, `[]`, is a Traversable.

With Semigroups, there's `sconcat`.